# Compiler Warning CS1701 when using csc.exe

Tags: c#

I'm trying to compile by command line a series of cs into a dll which uses Telerik.Web.UI.dll.

It compiles but I don't understand why I get this CS1701 warning about assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' as it says it's not sure it corresponds to 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' and that I should provide a runtime strategy.

What all this mumbo jumbo, how to fix it ?

Update: command line used

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe /t:library *.cs /out:test.dll /r:"C:\Program Files\Telerik\RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX Q3 2009\Bin\Telerik.Web.UI.dll"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds as if your project is using .NET 3.5 and you have a .NET 1 version of System.Web.Extensions.  Make sure all of your dlls are using .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to assume certain responsibilities to get command-line compiling right.  That includes uses the correct /reference options and making sure that the correct version of csc.exe gets started so it uses the correct .rsp file.  The real source of the warning (which you should *not* ignore) is unguessable if you don't post the command line that you used.

Comment: How was your command environment set up?  Usually done with "Visual Studio Command prompt", what version of VS?

Comment: Originally it was 2005. As for the path I have no problem with that since it compiles as I got my dll.